# MySQL Query to combine two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a MySQL query to combine two tables. Both tables have a user_id and date column and the other columns are unique to each table. What I'm looking to accomplish is best explained with an image ([imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6OTQ.jpg)). I've tried various joins and unions and can't get the right combination. I've also tried searching stackoverflow but I'm likely not using the right terminology for what I'm looking to do.

The description of the tables in TEXT:

```
tablel 
user_id date       animals 
1       9/15/2020  Lion 
2       8/11/2020  Tiger 
3       12/12/2020 Bear 

table2 
user_id date      fruit 
1       7/7/2020  apple 
2       6/5/2020  pear 
4       3/8/2020  peach

output 
user_id date        animals fruit 
1       9/15/2020   Lion 
1       7/7/2020            apple 
2       8/11/2020   Tiger 
2       6/5/2020            pear
3       12/12/2020  Bear 
4       3/8/2020            peach
```

Comment: I Think the description is much clearer in text, than in the picture.

Comment: Please add what you tried, together with info why it failed. Please also add the version of mysql you are using.

Comment: Thanks Luuk. I'm still learning.

Comment: I didn't keep any of the previous script attempts unfortunately. I tried a lot of combinations in mysql workbench and since none worked I didn't save anything. I'm using MySQL 8.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With UNION ALL you can achieve that

```
SELECT user_id, date, animals, fruit FROM
(
      SELECT user_id, date, animals, '' as fruit
        FROM table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT user_id, date, '', fruit
        FROM table2
 ) t
 ORDER BY user_id, animals
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT user_id, date, animals, '' as fruit
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id AND table1.date = table2.date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- use test;
-- drop table if exists table1;
create table table1(user_id int, `date` date, animals varchar(10));
insert into table1 values(1,'2020/09/15','Lion');
insert into table1 values(2,'2020/11/08','Tiger');
insert into table1 values(3,'2020/12/12','Bear');

-- drop table if exists table2;
create table table2(user_id int, `date` date, fruit varchar(10));
insert into table2 values(1,'2020/07/07','apple');
insert into table2 values(2,'2020/05/06','pear');
insert into table2 values(4,'2020/08/03','peach');

select 
  user_id,
  `date`,
  animals,
  '' as fruit
from table1
union all
select
  user_id,
  `date`,
  '',
  fruit
from table2
order by user_id,`date`;
```

output:

```
+ ------------ + --------- + ------------ + ---------- +
| user_id      | date      | animals      | fruit      |
+ ------------ + --------- + ------------ + ---------- +
| 1            | 2020-07-07 |              | apple      |
| 1            | 2020-09-15 | Lion         |            |
| 2            | 2020-05-06 |              | pear       |
| 2            | 2020-11-08 | Tiger        |            |
| 3            | 2020-12-12 | Bear         |            |
| 4            | 2020-08-03 |              | peach      |
+ ------------ + --------- + ------------ + ---------- +
```

Answer (score 0):

the more simple query to understand it would be :

```
SELECT * FROM tablel, table2 WHERE table1.user_id = table2.user_id
```

the second table need to have a foreign key, that have the id like the fisrt table, this query that I show you works like a INNER JOIN.